# Spark stuck in UDF on aws cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, udf

I have a `Spark` job that retrieve data from a few `Redshift` tables, applies some transformations like `join` and `groupby` and also applies some `UDFs` to some columns.

I have executed in Spark stand alone in my local machine and it works properly. But when I execute in the `aws` cluster it stucks on the `udf`, because I have tried removing the `udf` and it works.
Related to that I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157322/spark-dataframe-in-python-execution-stuck-when-using-udfs)

I need to use the `UDFs` but if I use the job stucks like 2 or 3 hours at that tasks and the `spark job` finishes without error, only stops.

Anyone has exeprienced something similar? Any help will be appreciated

**EDIT:**

When I remove the `UDFs` the job works properly.

But whith the `UDFs` it stucks with few tasks remaining, here the end of the logs:

stdout log:

```
2017-06-07T09:18:01.929+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-06-07T09:18:01.929+0000: [ParNew: 66492K->2341K(72512K),
0.0024644 secs] 648682K->584531K(1042416K), 0.0025210 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]  2017-06-07T09:18:01.962+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-06-07T09:18:01.962+0000: [ParNew: 66758K->2487K(72512K), 0.0022863 secs] 648948K->584677K(1042416K),
0.0023321 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]  2017-06-07T09:18:02.001+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-06-07T09:18:02.001+0000: [ParNew: 66999K->3757K(72512K),
0.0028101 secs] 649189K->585953K(1042416K), 0.0028601 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]  2017-06-07T09:18:02.030+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-06-07T09:18:02.030+0000: [ParNew: 68269K->2462K(72512K), 0.0019834 secs] 650465K->584706K(1042416K),
0.0020289 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]  2017-06-07T09:18:02.130+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-06-07T09:18:02.130+0000: [ParNew: 66974K->6797K(72512K),
0.0038833 secs] 649218K->589043K(1042416K), 0.0039409 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]  2017-06-07T09:18:02.309+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-06-07T09:18:02.309+0000: [ParNew: 71311K->8000K(72512K), 0.0209973 secs] 653556K->595016K(1042416K),
0.0210531 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]  2017-06-07T09:18:02.331+0000: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) 2017-06-07T09:18:02.331+0000: [ParNew: 8632K->3373K(72512K), 0.0131140 secs] 595648K->595234K(1042416K), 0.0131557 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]  2017-06-07T09:22:28.879+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-06-07T09:22:28.879+0000: [ParNew: 67885K->1862K(72512K), 0.0018928 secs] 659746K->593723K(1042416K),
0.0019463 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]  2017-06-07T09:27:48.879+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-06-07T09:27:48.879+0000: [ParNew: 66374K->1231K(72512K),
0.0014260 secs] 658235K->593093K(1042416K), 0.0014730 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]  2017-06-07T09:33:08.879+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-06-07T09:33:08.879+0000: [ParNew: 65743K->1075K(72512K), 0.0016924 secs] 657605K->592937K(1042416K),
0.0017409 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
```

stderr log:

```
17/06/07 09:18:02 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
17/06/07 09:18:02 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 1 non-empty blocks out of 1200 blocks
17/06/07 09:18:02 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
17/06/07 09:18:02 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 1 non-empty blocks out of 1 blocks
17/06/07 09:18:02 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
17/06/07 09:18:02 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 1200 blocks
17/06/07 09:18:02 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
17/06/07 09:18:02 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 29.410073 ms
17/06/07 09:18:02 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 8.06304 ms
17/06/07 09:18:02 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 12.481201 ms
17/06/07 09:18:02 INFO MemoryStore: Block rdd_368_10 stored as values in memory (estimated size 928.0 B, free 5.4 GB)
17/06/07 09:18:02 INFO MemoryStore: Block rdd_368_9 stored as values in memory (estimated size 928.0 B, free 5.4 GB)
17/06/07 09:18:02 INFO MemoryStore: Block rdd_368_3 stored as values in memory (estimated size 904.0 B, free 5.4 GB)
17/06/07 09:18:02 INFO MemoryStore: Block rdd_368_15 stored as values in memory (estimated size 904.0 B, free 5.4 GB)
17/06/07 09:18:02 INFO MemoryStore: Block rdd_368_13 stored as values in memory (estimated size 888.0 B, free 5.4 GB)
17/06/07 09:18:02 INFO MemoryStore: Block rdd_368_5 stored as values in memory (estimated size 904.0 B, free 5.4 GB)
17/06/07 09:18:02 INFO MemoryStore: Block rdd_368_12 stored as values in memory (estimated size 904.0 B, free 5.4 GB)
17/06/07 09:18:02 INFO MemoryStore: Block rdd_368_8 stored as values in memory (estimated size 928.0 B, free 5.4 GB)
17/06/07 09:18:02 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 17.574289 ms
17/06/07 09:18:02 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 8.639658 ms
Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching ['/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1496824216933_0005', '/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/filecache/157/pyspark.zip/pyspark']Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching ['/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1496824216933_0005', '/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/filecache/157/pyspark.zip/pyspark']

Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching ['/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1496824216933_0005', '/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/filecache/157/pyspark.zip/pyspark']
Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching ['/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1496824216933_0005', '/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/filecache/157/pyspark.zip/pyspark']Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching ['/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1496824216933_0005', '/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/filecache/157/pyspark.zip/pyspark']

Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching ['/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1496824216933_0005', '/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/filecache/157/pyspark.zip/pyspark']
Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching ['/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1496824216933_0005', '/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/filecache/157/pyspark.zip/pyspark']
Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching ['/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1496824216933_0005', '/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/filecache/157/pyspark.zip/pyspark']
```

Why using the `UDFs` the message `Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching` ... ??

Comment: We can't help you if we can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Edited post and added logs

Comment: @Alezis I'm facing the same problem, Can you post how you fixed this ?